# InboxSDK get all attachments in a thread

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, gmail-addons, inboxsdk

Is there any way to get the title of all attachments in an email thread with [InboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/)? I see there is a method `getTitle` under `AttachmentCardView` but if the message itself is not loaded, the attachment card view does not show up. I have tried using `messageView.getFileAttachmentCardViews()` on unloaded messages, but it just returns an empty array. Is there any way to do this natively with InboxSDK? the next thing I can think of is using the Gmail API, but I don't want to make multiple requests for every email in any thread that the user opens.